# Join em 3 tabelas

Tags: sql-server, select, join

Preciso que minha query retorne quem é o socio direto da empresa "Pai" e a empresa "filha". Já consegui que ele me retornasse a empresa filha e o sócio direto, porém preciso que ele me retorne se a empresa filha tem sócio. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PessoaJuridica] (
[Id]          INT          IDENTITY (2, 1) NOT NULL,
[Nome]        VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[CNPJ]        VARCHAR (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC));

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PessoaFisica] (
[Id]          INT          IDENTITY (1, 3) NOT NULL,
[nome]        VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[CPF]         VARCHAR (50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC));


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Filhoes] (
[Id]              INT IDENTITY (2, 1) NOT NULL,
[idFisicaFilho]   INT NULL,
[idJuridicaPai]   INT NULL,
[idJuridicaFilho] INT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_JuridicaFilho] FOREIGN KEY ([idJuridicaFilho]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PessoaJuridica] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_JuridicaPai] FOREIGN KEY ([idJuridicaPai]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PessoaJuridica] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_PessoaFisica] FOREIGN KEY ([idFisicaFilho]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PessoaFisica] ([Id]));
```

A query:

```
SELECT * FROM Filhoes
```

Retorna:

```
Id   |idFisicaFilho |idJuridicaPai |idJuridicaFilho
 1   | NULL         | 1003         | 1004
 2   | 3004         | 1003         | NULL
 3   | 3007         | 1004         | NULL
```

E a query:

```
SELECT
    pjf.Nome,
    pjf.CNPJ,
    pf.nome,
    pf.CPF
    FROM Filhoes f
    LEFT JOIN PessoaJuridica pjp on pjp.Id = f.idJuridicaPai    
    LEFT JOIN PessoaJuridica pjf on pjf.Id = f.idJuridicaFilho
    LEFT JOIN PessoaFisica pf on pf.Id = f.idFisicaFilho
    WHERE f.idJuridicaPai = '1003'
```

Retorna:

```
Subordinado | CNPJ                |Socio    |CPF
 teste2     | 29.788.592/0001-30  |  NULL   | NULL
 NULL       | NULL                | Joaquim | 664.341.440-75
```

Como deveria retornar:

```
Subordinado | CNPJ                |Socio    |CPF
 teste2     | 29.788.592/0001-30  |  José   | 494.737.180-39
 NULL       | NULL                | Joaquim | 664.341.440-75
```

Comment: Fala Arthur. Edita sua pergunta com a estrutura das tabelas envolvidas.

Comment: Importante [edit] descrevendo melhor a estrutura de cada uma das tabelas, e um exemplo de como deveria ser o resultado (com os respectivos dados que dão origem à saída pretendida), algo como um [MCVE]. Considerando que você só está usando `pfj` e `pf` nos campos do select, só retornarão duas tabelas mesmo. Se puder, ainda, complementar com um [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) ou similar (como complemento, a pergunta não deve depender de links externos) ajudaria a comunidade a propor soluções.

Comment: @ArthurAlberto (**1**) Uma empresa pode ter um único sócio ou pode ter mais de um sócio?  (**2**) Uma empresa pode ter uma única empresa filha ou pode ter várias empresas filhas? (**3**)  Uma mesma pessoa pode ser sócio em mais de uma empresa?

Comment: Arthur, fique atento à definição dos tamanhos da coluna de tamanho variável. Por exemplo, para o CPF utilize `char(11)`, para CNPJ utilize `char(14)`. Isto otimiza o gerenciamento de memória do SQL Server. Vide artigo https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/09/14/como-definir-o-tamanho-de-colunas-de-tamanho-variavel/

Comment: @JoséDiz (1) mais de um sócio, (2) varias empresas filhas, (3) Sim.

sobre a questão do `char` esse e apenas um modelo do projeto principal. Preciso criar esse select para gerar um relatório.